# Airflow DockerOperator volumes and mounts

Tags: docker, airflow, dockeroperator

We have Airflow running (using Docker compose) with several DAG's active. Last week we updated our Airflow to version 2.1.3.
This resulted in an error for a DAG where we use DockerOperator:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to DockerOperator (task_id: t_docker). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'volumes':
```

I found this [release note](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/index.html#id4) telling me that

> The volumes parameter in airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker.DockerOperator and airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker_swarm.DockerSwarmOperator was replaced by the mounts parameter

So I changed our DAG from

```
t_docker = DockerOperator(
        task_id='t_docker',
        image='customimage:latest',
        container_name='custom_1',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        volumes=['/home/airflow/scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts','/home/airflow/data:/opt/airflow/data'],
        docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
        network_mode='bridge',
        dag=dag
    )
```

to this

```
t_docker = DockerOperator(
        task_id='t_docker',
        image='customimage:latest',
        container_name='custom_1',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        mounts=['/home/airflow/scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts','/home/airflow/data:/opt/airflow/data'],
        docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
        network_mode='bridge',
        dag=dag
    )
```

But now i get this error:

```
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create?name=custom_1: Internal Server Error ("json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field HostConfig.HostConfig.Mounts of type mount.Mount")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The change isn't only in the parameter name it's also a change to [Mount syntax](https://docs.docker.com/storage).

You should replace

```
volumes=['/home/airflow/scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts','/home/airflow/data:/opt/airflow/data']
```

with:

```
mounts=[
    Mount(source="/home/airflow/scripts", target="/opt/airflow/scripts", type="bind"),
    Mount(source="/home/airflow/data", target="/opt/airflow/data", type="bind"),
]
```

So your code will be:

```
from docker.types import Mount
t_docker = DockerOperator(
    task_id='t_docker',
    image='customimage:latest',
    container_name='custom_1',
    api_version='auto',
    auto_remove=True,
    mounts=[
        Mount(source="/home/airflow/scripts", target="/opt/airflow/scripts", type="bind"),
        Mount(source="/home/airflow/data", target="/opt/airflow/data", type="bind"),
    ],
    docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
    network_mode='bridge',
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: I also had to include `mount_tmp_dir=False,`to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

How to dynamically pass the source path in mounts using xcom = [Mount...]

```
mounts=[Mount
(source=f"{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='retrieve_host_path') }}" , 
target=f"{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='retrieve_host_path') }}" , 
type="bind"
)],
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).